# No funciona el addEventListener en codigo autogenerado

Tags: javascript

no tengo idea de que pueda estar fallando o como hacerlo de una manera distinta. Tengo un json(menuData) al cual despues de aplicarle sort se genera por js el codigo html de un menú de opciones. El armado de html va muy bien pero el evento click no logro capturarlo y por ello no funcionan los enlaces a cargar dentro del contenedor.
Dejo código.

```
//codigo para event listener
const loadPage = (id, page) => {
  $(`#${id}`).on('click', function() {
    $('#contenedor').load(page);
  });
};

// codigo para generar el HTML del menú
const generateMenuHTML = (menuData) => {
  const menuContainer = document.getElementById('contenedor');

  menuData.forEach(menuItem => {
    const { id, nombreinterno, ruta, titulo, padre } = menuItem;

    if (padre == '-1') {
      const hasChildren = menuData.some(item => item.padre == id);
      const html = menuItemTemplate(nombreinterno, titulo, hasChildren);
      menuContainer.innerHTML += html;

      if (!hasChildren) {
        loadPage(nombreinterno, ruta);
      }
    } else {
      const parentItem = menuData.find(item => item.id == padre);
      const parentCollapseId = `collapse${parentItem.nombreinterno}`;

      const parentCollapse = document.getElementById(parentCollapseId);
      const subMenuContainer = parentCollapse.querySelector('.collapse-inner');
      const html = subMenuItemTemplate(nombreinterno, titulo);
      subMenuContainer.innerHTML += html;

      loadPage(nombreinterno, ruta);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Creo que debes encerrar en comillas todo lo que tienes en el template literal `$('`#${id}`').on('click', function() {`. Prueba con diferentes combinaciones _dentro y fuera de los backticks_ y si aún así no funciona, deja un comentario para analizar otras opciones. **Ojo, en este comentario desaparecen los backticks por ser una característica del sitio para resaltar código. Tenlo muy en cuenta. No lo copies. En tu código pon las comillas de forma manual.**

Comment: Lo intenté pero nada, coloqué los backticks en distintos lugares pero no funcionó. Cambié loadPage a function pero tampoco funcionó. No veo salida. Gracias por el comentario.

Comment: En tu código no se logra identificar donde pones un evento onclick, debes colocar un [MRE]

Comment: @Yussef en efecto, me he percatado que el evento queda dentro de la función loadPage() que luego no llamo. Podría agregar el evento onclick directamente al elemento <a> pero no me parece que sea lo mas apropiado. Ves alguna otra manera de lograr lo que necesito? Gracias de antemano

Comment: @JorgeCardenas Uufff es que yo pienso que los eventos inline funcionan perfecto para el 99% de los casos y en muchos funcionan mejor que el `addEventListener`, en frameworks como Angular o Blazor tu escribes los eventos dentro de la etiqueta. Entonces evidentemente mi respuesta es SI, no le des más vuelta y coloca el evento dentro del `<a>` y vas a ver que todo es más fácil